# get Input values dynamically in php

Tags: php, symfony

I am devolping a web application using symfony framework. I have a problem in forms. Here is my code:

```
$value = array(); 

foreach ($myArray as $value) {

$fieldNameAppend    ='<input type="radio" name="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'"  value="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" id="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" class="inputFields">'.$value.'';   
}   

print_r($fieldNameAppend);
```

In the loop i got all data in allValues variable.But when I access outside the loop i got only one value.

Please help

Comment: Yes, you didn't contatenate the string to $fieldNameAppend :) you just assign last string in the loop.

Comment: You use symfony yet you build forms *by hand*. [Why's that?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because u keep overwriting $fieldNameAppend.

YOu can try it this way to put all the inputs in the same string (notice the .=)

```
    fieldNameAppend = '';
foreach ($myArray as $value) {
    $fieldNameAppend    .='<input type="radio" name="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'"  value="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" id="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" class="inputFields">'.$value.'';   

}
echo $fieldNameAppend;
```

or to make a array:

```
    fieldNameAppend = array();

foreach ($myArray as $value) {

        $fieldNameAppend[]    ='<input type="radio" name="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'"  value="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" id="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" class="inputFields">'.$value.'';   

    }
print_r($fieldNameAppend);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `concatenate` **' .= '**  the variable to get all the dynamic inputs.

```
$fieldNameAppend    .='<input type="radio" name="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'"  value="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" id="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" class="inputFields">'.$value.'';
```

Comment: ensure $fieldNameAppend is assigned the empty string before the loop

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $strevalue = array();

  foreach ($myArray as $value) {

        $strevalue['value']    ='<input type="radio" name="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'"  value="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" id="'.$value.'Cleaning'.$id.'" class="inputFields">'.$value.'';   
        $val[] =$strevalue;

  }
  print_r($val);
```